# error en java = Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java

Después de investigar y no encontrar una solución a este problema decidí recurrir a este foro el código es simple y el error tal ves es tonto pero recién estoy empezando a escribir código, les dejo el código y el error adjunto, y si me pueden explicar todo lo que sepan sobre el, se los agradeseria muchísimo ya que me interesa aprender bien como funciona todo (esta escrito en java)

---

Acá dejo el código escrito:

```
   Cven = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese la cantidad de vendedores ");
   int cantVende = Integer.valueOf(Cven);

   int importe;
   int cont;
   int suma = 0;
   String vendedores[] = new String[cantVende];
   int importeTotal[] = new int[cantVende];
   int i;


    for ( i = 0; i < cantVende; i++) {
        int ii = i + 1 ;

     String vendedor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese el codigo del " + ii + "° vendedor ingrese \"x\" si desea finalizar ahora " );

        if ("x".equals(vendedor)) {
           String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("no a terminado de ingresar todos los vendedores, ingrese \"V\"si desea finalizar, de lo contrario ingrese cualquier otro caracter ");
            if ("v".equals(a)) {
                break;
            } 
            else{
                i -= 1 ;
                continue;
            }     
                                  }
        vendedores[i] = vendedor;

        importe = 1;
        suma = 0;
        cont = 0;
        while (importe != 0) {
          cont++;
          String importt =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese el "+ cont +"° importe del vendedor "+ vendedores[i] + " ingrese 0 para finalizar " );
          importe = Integer.valueOf(importt);

          suma += importe; 
                            }    
      importeTotal[i] = suma;
    }

    for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," es "+ "el importe de "+vendedores[a] );// esta es la linea que da error 

    }
```

---

El error es este:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>     at
>   compradores.y.ventas.CompradoresYVentas.main(CompradoresYVentas.java:65)

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu codigo, y el error deben estar copiados en la pregunta y no ser imagenes, porque no se ven

Comment: Por favor, intenta copiar y pegar el código en la pregunta, evita usar capturas de pantalla para eso, ya que vuelve muy complejo brindarte ayuda!

Comment: Saca int ii = i + 1 ; fuera del ciclo for

Comment: No es buena costumbre modificar el valor de la variable que utilizas para recorrer el bucle dentro del mismo bucle. Indica que linea es la que hace saltar la excepción. Aunque si en el primer intento, introduces una x y luego algo distinto a v te dara error porque decrementas i y luego intentas acceder a la posicion i-1 del array que sería -1 y ahí falla. Creo...

Comment: Te da el error porque al salir del bucle i = catvende y luego intentas acceder a la posición catvende del array que no existe, por eso te pasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta respuesta deberia ser un comentario, pero por formato lo dejo aca.

Al finalizar el bucle `for`:

```
for ( i = 0; i < cantVende; i++) { ... }
```

El valor de `i` sera igual que `cantVende`

Por lo que en tu ultimo `for`:

```
for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++) { ... }
```

En su ultima iteracion `a` sera tambien igual a `cantVende` y con eso `vendedores[a]` te dara un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Basta con que uses `a < i`

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Como ha dicho el compañero, la excepción corresponde a intentar acceder a una posición del array fuera de sus límites, como puede ser array[-1].

Unas recomendaciones que te puedo dar son las siguientes:

-Los break y continue son el diablo, trata de reorganizar tu algoritmo para no tener que usarlos.

-Usa nombres de variables mas descriptivos, "ii" no es un nombre para nada descriptivo, y el nombre "vendedor" par una variable que va a almacenar un código o bien un string "x", tampoco es adecuado. 
No tengas miedo de usar nombres de variables largos si eso va a hacer que tu código sea mas legible.

-No se considera una buena práctica hacer métodos o funciones de mas de 7-10 lineas, extrae bloques de código con funciones concretas y crea nuevas funciones que tengas un único fin.

-No uses lo que llamamos "Magic Strings", por ejemplo, si en tu función, un string "x" sirve para terminar la ejecución, no pases ese "x" tal y como lo has hecho, guarda ese String en una variable con un nombre descriptivo, por ejemplo "cerrar","terminar"